# Registering callback in PortAudio with Racket FFI causes segfault

Tags: racket, ffi, portaudio

I'm trying to write a Racket interface for PortAudio. Each audio stream has an associated callback function for playback; the FFI documentation says I should be able to pass a Racket procedure without issue. However, the function that registers the callback seems to cause a segmentation fault, which I assume is because I'm doing something wrong. From the library header:

```c
// portaudio.h
// ...

typedef int PaStreamCallback(
    const void *input, void *output,
    unsigned long frameCount,
    const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
    PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
    void *userData );
// ...

PaError Pa_OpenDefaultStream( PaStream** stream,
                          int numInputChannels,
                          int numOutputChannels,
                          PaSampleFormat sampleFormat,
                          double sampleRate,
                          unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                          PaStreamCallback *streamCallback, // <-----
                          void *userData );
```

I used the Racket FFI to import, with no complaints:

```racket
; portaudio.rkt
; ...

(define _PaStreamCallback
  (_fun #:atomic? #t
        _pointer _pointer
        _ulong
        _PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo-pointer
        _PaStreamCallbackFlags
        (_or-null _pointer)
        -> _PaStreamCallbackResult))

; ...

(define-portaudio Pa_OpenDefaultStream
  (_fun (s : (_ptr o _PaStream-pointer))
        _int _int
        _PaSampleFormat
        _double
        _ulong
        _PaStreamCallback ; <-----
        (_or-null _pointer)
        -> (r : _PaError)
        -> (begin (check r 'Pa_OpenDefaultStream) s))
  #:wrap (allocator Pa_CloseStream))
```

But the following now gives a segmentation fault:

```racket
(require "portaudio.rkt")

; ...

(define (stream-callback _1 output-buffer frame-count _2 _3 data)
    ... )

; ...

(define stream (Pa_OpenDefaultStream 0 (output-channel-count)
                                       (format-symbol->format (sample-format))
                                       (sample-rate)
                                       (frames-per-buffer)
                                       stream-callback
                                       #f))
```

The result is:

```
SIGSEGV MAPERR si_code 1 fault on addr (nil)
Aborted
```

Things I've tried (separately and in combination):

- Changing `_PaStreamCallback` to `_pointer` in the definition of `Pa_OpenDefaultStream`.
- Changing `_PaStreamCallback` to `(_ptr i _PaStreamCallback)` in the same definition.
- Passing `(function-ptr stream-callback _PaStreamCallback)` to `Pa_OpenDefaultStream` instead of just `stream-callback`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't see anything obvious. Maybe @john-clements has an idea? Maybe you can find the solution here. https://github.com/jbclements/portaudio/blob/74dfaf1d6317a9f5479ae5492e874e9e73888a46/portaudio/portaudio.rkt#L1383

Comment: Thanks -- I'll probably just use this premade solution. It looks like the author opted not to write his callbacks in Racket anyway, due to latency issues with the GC.

Answer (score 2):

This is John Clements--let me know if you have any issues with my portaudio Racket interface! you can install it with

`raco pkg install portaudio`

... assuming you're using racket 6 or later.

Comment: Seems to be working just fine. :) Although I still wonder what went wrong with my own implementation...